# How to send GPS cordinates and current moving speed to phone db with timestamp

Tags: android, gps

I'm new in to Android. I tried several ways to store GPS coordinates in my phone db.

Now the problem is I want to store GPS cordinates every x seconds with current moving vehicle speed and the time.

Also this function should start after a button click event.

Comment: This post describes how to define the service and store the positions in the database [service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44775200/4631177)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Gps as background service and Compare the received current Location Data with value in Sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148214/run-gps-as-background-service-and-compare-the-received-current-location-data-wit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a service and start a timer like shown below.Hope this helps

```
 public void starttimer(){
   timer = new CountDownTimer(300000, 2000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
           locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    try {
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    if(location==null) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    if (location != null) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double longg = location.getLongitude();
        mMap.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat,longg) , 14.0f) );


    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Device Failed To Fetch Lat Long", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    }


    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        //your code when timer finishes
    }
}.start();
  }
```

Comment: thnk you so much for the help @shivadeep

Comment: i need to store the gps cordinates with the current moving speed of the vehicle and the time

Comment: i am not sure about speed but you can store coordinates by writing it to txt file

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make one background service which will continuously fetch the GPS coordinates in every x seconds. The main reason behind making the service for this is when your application is not visible and it is minimized than also your service will be kept running and in the background of the application the GPS coordinates will be updated periodically.

For implementing you would need a FusedLocationAPI and GooglAPiClient. If you want a very simple code than follow this link:
[Android make method run every X seconds (involves gps and server call)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693799/android-make-method-run-every-x-seconds-involves-gps-and-server-call)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: thank you @Dwhitz for your suggestion, i will surely take your suggestion into consideration while answering the next question.

Comment: thnx much appreciate your answer @Pranay Soni